# Shapiro-Wilk test with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataset, normal-distribution

I have to perform a Shapiro-Wilk normality test. My dataset is build like this:

```
Condition0 <- c(0.9201584, 0.8386860, 0.8092635, 0.8166590, 0.8653545)
Condition1 <- c(0.9905397, 0.9498400, 1.0378111, 0.9740314, 1.0355568)
Condition2 <- c(0.9529179, 1.0919274, 1.0089470, 1.0067670, 0.9686904)
Condition3 <- c(0.7402958, 0.7890059, 0.8060471, 0.8020820, 0.7931508)
Condition4 <- c(0.7725662, 0.6916708, 0.7698080, 0.7476060, 0.7602339)
Control <- c(0.7707546, 0.7035131, 0.7268695, 0.8217838, 0.7641010)

dataset <- data.frame(Condition0, Condition1, Condition2, Condition3, Condition4, Control, row.names = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"))
```

As you see can there are 6 conditions with 5 results for each condition.

Is it right to do the Shapiro-Wilk test in this way, dividing the dataset for every single condition?

```
shapiro.test(dataset$Condition0)
shapiro.test(dataset$Condition1)
shapiro.test(dataset$Condition2)
shapiro.test(dataset$Condition3)
shapiro.test(dataset$Condition4)
shapiro.test(dataset$Control)
```

or, should I built my dataset in a different way and do the test in the whole dataset, regardless of the factor "condition"?
Like this:

```
    my_data <- c(0.9201584, 0.8386860, 0.8092635, 0.8166590, 0.8653545, 
              0.9905397, 0.9498400, 1.0378111, 0.9740314, 1.0355568,
              0.9529179, 1.0919274, 1.0089470, 1.0067670, 0.9686904,
              0.7402958, 0.7890059, 0.8060471, 0.8020820, 0.7931508,
              0.7725662, 0.6916708, 0.7698080, 0.7476060, 0.7602339,
             0.7707546, 0.7035131, 0.7268695, 0.8217838, 0.7641010)
cycle <- rep(c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"), 6)
Condition <- rep(c("Condition0","Condition1", "Condition2", "Condition3", "Condition4", "Control"), each = 5)

dataset2 <- data.frame(my_data, cycle, Condition)

shapiro.test(dataset2$my_data)
```

After the Shapiro-Wilk test I'll run an ANOVA or a Kruskall-Wallis (depends on the result) to see if there is any difference among different conditions. Like this:

```
my_lm <- lm(my_data ~ Condition, data= dataset2)
anova(my_lm)
```

Which one do you think is the correct one? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Run a non-parametric test, if you are not sure. I would start with your second approach, then perhaps using the first one. But this will depend on the data... The question fits better to http://stats.stackexchange.com/. There you might find more help.

Comment: A bigger concern is that it won't be a very robust statistical test anyway with only 5 observations per group. And it's hard to characterise the distribution with such a small sample size. I agree, try Stack Exchange perhaps.

Comment: thank you very much